# completionHandler / userCompletionHandler problem - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

I've got two functions below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath)
    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

    // Set table cell values

    getUserFriendlyName(sid: message.sid!, arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.friendly_name
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.body
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    return cell
}
```

and

```
func getUserFriendlyName(sid: String, arg: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    let ACCOUNT_IDENTITY: String = "AC***redacted"
    let AUTH_TOKEN: String = "**redacted"
    let SERVICE_ID: String = "IS***redacted"

    let loginString = "\(ACCOUNT_IDENTITY):\(AUTH_TOKEN)"

    let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let base64LoginString = loginData!.base64EncodedString()

    let url = URL(string: "https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/IS***redacted/Users/US***redacted")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    var session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //request.addValue(AUTH_TOKEN, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    var fn: String!
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        var strData = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("Body: \(strData)")
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data is empty")
            return
        }

        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

        //getting the json response
        print(json)
        fn = json["friendly_name"] as! String?
        self.friendly_name = fn

        completion(arg)
        //return fn
        //print(fn)
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

Here's the problem I'm running into... When a new chat message is detected, the tableView function gets called. A new cell is created with text and subtext. Because the native Twilio code doesn't allow me to display the friendly name of who wrote the chat, I have to go and make an HTTP call, so I call getUserFriendlyName(). Because resumeTask() is asynchronous, the flow of the program goes like this:

1. tableView function is entered
2. I make the call to the getUserFriendlyNameFunction(), which gets entered
3. When we get to the HTTP request, resumeTask() is called and then the flow returns back to the tableView function, specifically the end of the call to the friendly user name function and it executes the return Cell line, which means the cell is created but contains the prototype data, namely "Title" for the text and "Subtitle" for the description text.
4. The flow then goes back to the HTTP request and it gets executed
5. The flow returns to the line of code directly after the call to getUserFriendlyName() inside the tableView function. That code sets the text and detail text values to the data returned by the HTTP call. But at this point, the cell already exists in my tableView. So I'm left with just a cell containing "Text" and "Subtext".

What I've tried:

1. Adding tableView.reloadData() after the final lines of code in the tableView function are executed. This did not update the tableView with the data from the HTTP call. In fact, it continually refreshed the tableView over and over again.
2. Moving the final three lines of code to the same spot as the "return Cell" line. This also did not work.

I've come to believe my only hope is/are completionHandler / userCompletionHandler. I've played around with them for a long time and cannot get the desired outcome, which would be to have the first incoming chat message populated with the data from the HTTP request.

Can anyone help?

Comment: 1. Remove async call from `cellForRowAt`. 2. Make the async call and then update your table's data (self.messages). 3. Call tableView.reloadData(), making sure you're on the main thread..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive a message don't add it directly to messages array but first call

```
// this goes inside some function not cellForRowAt

let message =  // received 

getUserFriendlyName(sid: message.sid!, arg: true, completion: { (success) -> Void in 
       message....// set all needed properties
       self.messages.append(message)
       self.tableview.reloadRows(at:[IndexPath(row:messages.count - 1,section:0)],with:.none)
}
```

Don't do any asynchronous work inside `cellForRowAt` as it'll be be done every scroll , in addition it doesn't display the full data at the same time

---

Completion of `session.dataTask(with: request`  is in a background thread so consider

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  completion(arg)
}
```

---

You make `self.friendly_name`

```
self.friendly_name = fn
```

A vc property while it should be a property for every message object so not to mix with other messages senders

Comment: Okay, I understand. I think I see what you’re saying about Cellforrowat... I didn’t know it executed asynchronously as well. I’ll rearrange my code and once I have it working I’ll post the completed two methods. Thanks all!